# How can I modify/update a java.net.URI object?

Tags: java, uri, updates

Given a [`java.net.URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) object, I need to either:

- destructively modify one field on that object (e.g. the `path` component). However there are no `setX` methods, so it seems these objects are supposed to be immutable.
- construct a new `URI` object that is the same as the original except for a given field ("functional update"). However there are no `withX` methods, so I would have to write my own logic to deal with this.

Do I really have to write my own functions to deal with modification of `URI` objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you would have create a new object each time since the `java.net.URI` is immutable. You may use a third-party class like Apache HttpComponents' [URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html).

Example from the [official tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html):

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
    .setScheme("http")
    .setHost("www.google.com")
    .setPath("/search")
    .setParameter("q", "httpclient")
    .setParameter("btnG", "Google Search")
    .setParameter("aq", "f")
    .setParameter("oq", "")
    .build();    // the build method creates a new URI instance behind the scenes
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the `setX` methods on `URIBuilder` actually do? The docs don't say.

Comment: I guess it would set a field in the `URIBuilder` instance that you create. After setting all URI components, you can get a new `URI` instance using `URIBuilder#build()`.